# internal forces in truss

Tags: structural-engineering

For this problem , i found that the internal force AB at point A and point B pointed in the same direction ( as shown) in my working , so , how they cancel off each other ???Since they cant cancel off each other , so they are not stable , right ? The structure is statically indeterminate ?

[image: 22]
[image: 222]

[image: 2131]

Comment: Your recent edit has nothing to do with this question, so I'll offer just this comment as an answer to it. You want vertical displacements at C, so apply a vertical unit load (1 kN) at that point and calculate the structure for that load. That gives you the respective virtual forces.

Comment: How to get the value of $\mu$?

Comment: I'm not going to answer that, since it shows a blatant lack of understanding of what virtual forces are (see what I mean when I say you seem to lack foundational knowledge?). If you don't understand how $\mu$ is related to my previous comment, go back to your books or ask a specific question about what it is ***precisely*** about virtual forces that you don't understand.

Comment: it's not stated in my book... Perhaps you can explain it ? Or you can provide any link that provide explaination ??

Comment: Virtual forces are an important part of the stiffness matrix method used to solve statically indeterminate structures. Any structural engineering book worth its salt will have to discuss them at some point in time. Virtual forces are also not at all trivial, so you can't ask someone to teach them to you on a site like this. And "reference requests" are off-topic on this site. That being said, [LMGTFY](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=virtual+forces).

Comment: @kelvinmacks - One question per post only. If you want to know about virtual forces, you would need to ask a separate question. I have removed your edit. (FYI - I don't recall virtual forces being taught in my university civil engineering course. Could be that I've plain forgotten though.)

Comment: I've spent the last few decades working on finite element software and never heard the term "virtual forces" in that time. But from @Wasabi's google link, it just looks like a case of different specialisms using different terminology - though personally I thought that way of formulating finite elements went out of fashion in the 1950s and 60s when people lost interest in trying to write software using what they then called "force methods." (There's nothing wrong with it for hand calculations, but computers don't necessarily work well by using the exact same steps as humans to solve a problem!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AndyT stated, you need to add the horizontal reaction at A.

You start by finding the reactions. Your global equilibrium equations are

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_x &= R_{A,x} + F = 0 \\
\therefore R_{A,x} &= -F = -4\text{ kN} \\
\sum F_y &= R_{A,y} + R_{B,y} = 0 \\
\therefore R_{A,y} &= -R_{B,y} \\
\sum M_A &= 8R_{B,y} - 3F = 0 \\
\therefore R_{B,y} &= \dfrac{3F}{8} = 1.5\text{ kN} \\
\therefore R_{A,y} &= -1.5\text{ kN}
\end{align}$$

Now, looking at the nodal equilibrium diagrams, we have for B:

[image]

Before going into the math, it is worth noting that this truss is composed of two [3-4-5 triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangle#Common_Pythagorean_triples), so we already know $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ are 5 m long.

So $\overline{BC}$ is the only member that can resist the vertical reaction, and it does so by suffering compression equal to

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_{B,y} &= R_{B,y} + \dfrac{3\overline{BC}}{5} = 0 \\
\therefore \overline{BC} &= -\dfrac{5R_{B,y}}{3} = -2.5\text{ kN (compression)} \\
\sum F_{B,x} &= \overline{AB} + \dfrac{4\overline{BC}}{5} = 0 \\
\therefore \overline{AB} &= -\dfrac{4\overline{BC}}{5} = 2\text{ kN (tension)} 
\end{align}$$

And then looking at A:

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_{A,y} &= R_{A,y} + \dfrac{3\overline{AC}}{5} = 0 \\
\therefore \overline{AC} &= -\dfrac{5R_{A,y}}{3} = 2.5\text{ kN (tension)} \\
\sum F_{A,x} &= R_{A,x} + \overline{AB} + \dfrac{4\overline{BC}}{5} = 0 \\
\therefore \overline{AB} &= -\dfrac{4\overline{BC}}{5} - R_{A,x} = 2\text{ kN (tension)} 
\end{align}$$

Both nodes agree that $\overline{AB}$ is in tension, so it checks out. Also, $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ have equal but opposite results, which is as it should be (and, if you actually do the work for node C, you'll see they are also correct).

Comment: Global equilibrium here means we consider the forces in equilibrium of the whole structure ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: It's the basic equilibrium equations you use for any structure to find its reactions. For instance, how did you find $V_A$ and $V_B$ (using your nomenclature) in your attempted answer?